# ssis OLE DB destination performance improvement

Tags: ssis

I run ssis package for insert data from huge flat file (more then million rows)

into mssql database with OLE DB destination.

Its works fine, but very slowly.

Any idea to improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this too.

I run it in sql server and saved the package from sql server and it seems that the difference is that you need to open the properties window of the destination (F4 key or double click on the cube)

And set `AccessMode = OpenRowset Using FastLoad`

It works currently great!